# export bash function in perl stopped working

Tags: bash, perl, function

I updated my machine from centOS 5.6 to centOS 5.10 and the following Perl code stop working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$ENV{TEST}="() {
    echo 'Hello world!'
}";

system("echo 'hope it works!' ; TEST");
```

Output in 5.6:

```
hope it works!
Hello world!
```

Output in 5.10:

```
hope it works!
sh: TEST: command not found
```

For some reason I am unable to set functions from Perl anymore!?!  IT looks like the bash and Perl version are the same, not sure what else it could be?

Comment: could this be related? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29

Comment: Indeed. This is exactly what the fix for shellshock prevents. Why were you doing it like this anyway?

Comment: I have a script that I use to list a  set of tar files and extract them.  In the script i define a function I use to display the progress of the tar command:                        system("$runPriority tar -xzf $tarballPath --checkpoint 2>&1 | TarProgress $tarRecordCount");

Answer (score 3):

That [extremely serious bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) in `bash` has been fixed. The severity cannot be understated because it allowed people to execute arbitrary code on many web servers.

You can still define functions from within `bash`.

```
$ TEST() { echo 'Hello world!'; }

$ TEST
Hello world!
```

Or in your case,

```
$ perl
system("TEST() { echo 'Hello world!'; }; echo 'hope it works!'; TEST");
^D
hope it works!
Hello world!
```

Comment: I tried adding the function to my .bashrc so that the perl command can just call it with out having to define the function.  This still did not work, I still get "command not found"?!?!

Comment: `bash` executes different startup scripts depending on whether it was started as `bash` or as `sh`. Use the right file, or use `system('bash', '-c', '...')`. You could also create a script rather than a function.